# Meta name apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style

Tags: jquery, html

i tried to do a little application for myself.

i have add the meta name:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

and this is my header code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"  data-id="footer">                
    </div>
```

when i add the shortcut icon and open the app my header is under the status bar

what is the problem?

Comment: do you mean put meta status bar befor meta capable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If set to black-translucent, the web content is displayed on the entire screen, partially obscured by the status bar."

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Try `default` or `black`.